# Deducting Fourier Transform pair from existing pair

Tags: fourier-transform

I need to determine Fourier Transform of  $\delta(2\pi f) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \delta (f)$  [Note: $\delta$ is Unit impulse function]

Answer is written in my book as follows :

\begin{align}
F^{-1}[\delta(2\pi f)] & = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(2\pi f)e^{j2\pi ft} \, df = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(2\pi f)e^{j2\pi ft} \, d(2\pi f) \\[10pt]
& =\frac{1}{2\pi}
\end{align}

Therefore,

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\Longleftrightarrow \delta(2 \pi f)$$

$$1 \Longleftrightarrow  \delta(f)$$

Here, the left part is in time domain and the right part is in frequency domain.
I understood inverse fourier integral part. But couldn't understand how we could deduct the last line from it's upper one.  I know that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta (f) e^{j2\pi ft} \, df =1$. I just need to know if there is any way of deducting further Fourier transform pair from an existing one by multiplication or division as it seems to be happened here.

Comment: For functions, you have $$ \mathcal{F}^{-1} \big(f(Cx)\big)(\xi) = \int f(Cx) e^{ix\xi} \,dx = [u=Cx]= \frac{1}{C}\int_{} f(u) e^{iu\xi/C} \, du = \frac{1}{C} \mathcal{F}^{-1} (f)(\xi/C).$$ A similar thing happens with distributions.

Comment: Why is $\delta(2\pi f) = \tfrac 1{2\pi}\delta(f)$. The symbol $\delta$ here is a distribution that maps a function $f$ to a value, namely to $f(0)$. So, $\delta(2\pi f) = 2\pi f(0) = 2\pi\delta(f)$.

Comment: @amsmath The $f$ is not the function here, but the argument of the Fourier transform. The distribution usually written $\delta(ax)$ is indeed the same as $\frac1{|a|} \delta(x)$ (you want formal integration by parts to work correctly, and give the same result as for a sequence of functions converging to a delta).

Comment: @Kusma What is $\delta(ax)$ here?

Comment: $\delta(af)$ is defined (for $a>0$) via change of variables by  $\int g(f) \delta(af) df= \int g(\frac s a) \delta(s) \frac 1a ds = \frac1a g(0)$.

Comment: More formally, $\delta_a$ written as "$\delta(af)$" is the linear map $\delta_a[g]=\frac1a g(0)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an property that helps in this case. 
It is the Linearity property of Fourier Transform. 
It says, if 
\begin{align}
g_1(t)\Longleftrightarrow G_1(f) ~ ~~~~~and  ~~~~~~ g_2(t)\Longleftrightarrow G_2(f)
\end{align}
then, 
\begin{align}
\sum_{k}^{}a_kg_k(t) \Longleftrightarrow \sum_{k}^{}a_kG_k(f) 
\end{align}
For any constants $\{a_k\}$ and signal $\{g_k(t)\}$. 
If we take the signal $g_1(t)$ n times then corresponding fourier tansform $G_1(f)$ must be taken n times too. 
\begin{align}
ng_1(t) \Longleftrightarrow nG_1(f) 
\end{align}
Correspondingly if, 
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\Longleftrightarrow \delta(2 \pi f)$$
then using linearity property, (**The following line was skipped in the book**)
$$1 \Longleftrightarrow  2\pi \delta(2 \pi f)$$
But according to question,   $\delta(2\pi f) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \delta (f)$
$$1 \Longleftrightarrow  \delta(f)  $$